# In polar chart, connect each series on base with an individual line

Tags: highcharts

I need to connect each series dot on a specific base in a polar chart type. Basically this polar starts from `-5` (as center of polar, but it is not visible), but I like to connect it from `0` until the series values.

**It is what I have currently:** http://jsfiddle.net/s9h6ry8r/

**It is what I need:**

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the scatter series with null points, which allows to print that kind of chart.

```
series: [{
  type: 'scatter',
  lineWidth: 2,
  data: [
    [0, 20], {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    null, [45, 30], {

      x: 45,
      y: 0,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    null
  ]
}]
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/s38w1b28/

Comment: It solves totally my problem and very easy to configure. Thanks a lot!